# No puedo enviar correo en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

NO puedo enviar correos desde mi apllicacion en rails, la versión de rails que manejo es **5.1.2**.

Adjunto pedazos de código:

> app/mailers/example_mailer.rb

```
class ExampleMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'haierhke@gmail.com'
  def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Sample Email')
  end
end
```

> app/views/example_mailer/sample_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      Sample mail sent using smtp.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

> test/mailers/previews/example_mailer_preview.rb

```
class ExampleMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def sample_mail_preview
    ExampleMailer.sample_email(User.first)
  end
end
```

> /config/application.yml

gmail_username: 'xxx@gmail.com'
gmail_password: 'xxx'

> /config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
 :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
 :authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

> app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save

      # Sends email to user when user is created.
      ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver

      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**Adjunto el log de salida**

```
Started GET "/users/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-26 06:39:40 -0400
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (103.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 419ms (Views: 355.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started PATCH "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-26 06:39:45 -0400
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"7wdXKYpv+o+tNlmBBSdgIcOa0d07f6fUlFnJqZC1zbVyfLrhct57mLZQBd0EOP9Ckmsw9LoAlSfeMt2wjg1eLw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"rafael Guillermo R", "email"=>"rrg1459@hotmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["name", "rafael Guillermo R"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-26 10:39:45.599798"], ["id", 1]]
   (137.4ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering example_mailer/sample_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered example_mailer/sample_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
  Rendering example_mailer/sample_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered example_mailer/sample_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (1.0ms)
ExampleMailer#sample_email: processed outbound mail in 364.2ms
Sent mail to rrg1459@hotmail.com (2021.4ms)
Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 06:39:46 -0400
From: haierhke@gmail.com
To: rrg1459@hotmail.com
Message-ID: <597871721c2f3_1d342c744047949e@A001044638.mail>
Subject: Sample Email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_597871721a39a_1d342c7440479395";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_597871721a39a_1d342c7440479395
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi rafael Guillermo R
Sample mail sent using smtp.

----==_mimepart_597871721a39a_1d342c7440479395
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi rafael Guillermo R</h1>
    <p>
      Sample mail sent using smtp.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_597871721a39a_1d342c7440479395--

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 2552ms (ActiveRecord: 140.4ms)


Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-26 06:39:48 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 345ms (Views: 299.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Antes que cualquier cosa, las credenciales de tu smtp son correctas (user_name, password)?

Comment: Si amigo, es mi correo personal, lo puse en triple xxx por razones obvias .

Comment: en gmail ocupas darle permisos de poder enviar correos, son cosas de seguridad de gmail, ya las activaste? este video te explica como: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-NYmDWiFjU

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra el log cuando intentas enviar el correo?, ¿podrías incluirlo en la pregunta?

Comment: 1) Donde y como puedo añadir el log???

Comment: 2) hice exactamente lo que dice el video de youtube y nada

Comment: El log lo puedes ver en `log/production.rb` (por el código que compartiste asumo que estás en producción, ¿es así?). ¿Te funciona en el ambiente de desarrollo?

Comment: lo que quise preguntar es como puedo editar la pregunta para agregar el log?

Comment: Ohh, debes tener un link abajo ee la pregunta que diga editar, dale clic ahí y podrás agregar más información a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que la configuración de tu ambiente está incompleta o bien, la validación está fallando, y al ver tu log todo indica que los errores de correo están silenciados, así que es difícil depurar de esa forma.

Para poder detectar el error claramente abre el archivo de configuración de ambiente (en tu caso, *production.rb*) y verifica que tengas esta línea:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Esta línea está habilitada con el valor `false`, así que debes cambiarla a `true`. Una vez realizado este cambio reinicia el servidor e intenta enviar el correo de nuevo; en esta ocasión te mostrará un mensaje con el error que está evitando que puedas enviar el correo.

Si estás trabajando en el ambiente de desarrollo, debes copiar la configuración del correo también en *development.rb* y agregar la siguiente línea<sup>1</sup>:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>*El valor por defecto es `false`, lo que evita que se envíen correos desde el ambiente de desarrollo.*</sup>

Comment: Hice lo queme indico y este fue el error que me arrojo:Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1520ms (ActiveRecord: 146.0ms)



Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in `block in update'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:51:in `update'

Comment: @rrg1459  Al parecer la autentificación con google no está funcionando; verifica tus credenciales (en la configuración del ambiente) y que hayas seguido el proceso para agregar dispositivos en google.

Comment: Buenos días,

primero que nada, pido disculpas por la tardanza en responder, pero la conexiones en Internet en mi país son de muy malas a pésimas (nada nuevo bajo el sol), estoy despierto desde la madrugada, ya que a esa hora es que la conexiones son mas o menos estables, Le explico lo que pude hacer, cree una nueva cuenta y le dia acceso a conexiones menos seguras y le habilite el IMAP, actualice las credenciales con la nueva cuenta gmail y su clave y me da el siguiente error:

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A):

Comment: @rrg1459 Intenta agregar `:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'` como una opción más dentro de `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { ... }`.

Comment: Excelente amigo, eso era lo que faltaba, una ultima pregunta, para que corra en heroku, hay que ponerle algún parámetro adicional???

Comment: @rrg1459 No es necesario, utilizarías las mismas credenciales; sin embargo, para un ambiente productivo te recomendaría utilizar un servicio para este fin; en Heroku puedes utilizar _[SendGrid](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid)_, el cual tiene una versión gratis que podrías utilizar.